# How to make async calls from List.ForEach C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have list of items and for each item i want to call the UploadChunkToServer method but in parallel. There will always be only 4 items in the list.

```
if (DataQueue.Count == NumberofChunksToRead)
{
    DataQueue.ToList().ForEach(Chunk =>
    {
        UploadChunkToServer(Chunk);
    });
}
```

Above is my code call in the method and the method signature is as follows.

```
private void UploadChunkToServer(UserCustomFile Chunk)
{
    var client = new RestClient(Helper.GetServerURL());

    var request = new RestRequest("api/fileupload/savechunk", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddJsonBody(Chunk);

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            ChunkStatuses.Add(Chunk.ChunkID);
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to add the async operator but no luck. Any ideas how this could be accomplished?

Comment: *I have tried to add the async operator but no luck* what does *no luck* mean? Compile errors? Behavior not different? Something else?

Comment: Generally, calling something asynchronously is not the same as doing something in parallel (in your case it would lead to parallelization on the server, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can make use of [Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) and ForEach in specific:

```
Parallel.ForEach(DataQueue.ToList(), Chunk =>
                 {
                      UploadChunkToServer(Chunk);
                 });
```

Comment: Parallel + IO bound tasks = a bit wasteful

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

DataQueue.ToList().ForEach(chunk =>
{
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => UploadChunkToServer(chunk)));
});

await tasks.WhenAll();
```

But you should change `UploadChunkToServer` to return something; a `bool` indicating if the upload was succesful. `void Tasks` should be avoided, pun intended...

UPDATE: As TheBoyan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48060758/767890) points out, you can simplify this making `UploadChunkToServer` async, but I'd still recommend returning something so you can get a hold on the tasks for later processing. If its a fire and forget scenario, this wouldn't be necessary:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

DataQueue.ToList().ForEach(chunk =>
{
    tasks.Add(UploadChunkToServer(chunk));
});

await tasks.WhenAll();
```

And `UploadChunkToServer` would look like:

```
private async Task<bool> UploadChunkToServer(UserCustomFile Chunk)
{
    var client = new RestClient(Helper.GetServerURL());

    var request = new RestRequest("api/fileupload/savechunk", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddJsonBody(Chunk);

    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            ChunkStatuses.Add(Chunk.ChunkID);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, and I think you have mixed up asynchronous and parallel, which are not necessarily the same in C#.

There is two types of **asynchrony** in C#:

- I/O bound (read/write over network etc.)
- Long running (high processing etc.)

Yours is a I/O bound operation, so it works by notifying the caller when it's done(by providing a state machine in the background). Think of it as an event based pattern.

The way you deal with it best is await if you already have an [YourMethodName]Async method provided by an API or a library, or [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to implement it yourself. Note that you don't necessarily need a parallel thread to implement it(by running Task.Run or some other way), the framework (or the one that implemented the method did it for you in the case of [YourMethodName]Async) provides a Task when it's done for you already.

So, if you want to make your method run `client.ExecuteAsync` asynchronously assuming ExecuteAsync returns a `Task`.
In your code you can do like this:

```
// add async keyword to notify that you are awaitng int he method
// perhaps also change the void to Task
private async Task UploadChunkToServer(UserCustomFile Chunk)
{
    var client = new RestClient(Helper.GetServerURL());

    var request = new RestRequest("api/fileupload/savechunk", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddJsonBody(Chunk);

    //add await operator to make this part run acync
    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            ChunkStatuses.Add(Chunk.ChunkID);
        }
    });
}
```

then further up in your call stack:

```
  if (DataQueue.Count == NumberofChunksToRead)
  {
       DataQueue.ToList().ForEach(Chunk =>
       {
           await UploadChunkToServer(Chunk);
       });
  }
```

You also might want to consider returning a result with Task, so that you can follow the progress or see which ones have already been uploaded etc.

If you want to run the method in **parallel**, the previous answer with *Parallel* *Foreach* will do the job. Although, I think it's not good to do that in this case since you have an I/O bound operation. What you basically would be doing is running a long running task that does nothing but wait most of the time. In the case of a 4 core processor and with you spawning 4 threads that would mean you occupy all of them by just waiting. Something that you are already been doing with await in the first place.

Comment: This as it is, could potentially be inconvenient due to fact that `UploadChunkToServer` is returning `void` so the caller can't get his hands on a `Task`. Its a possibility (my interpretation) that the OP wants to use some sort of `WhenAll` or similar once all tasks are done. If this were a fire and forget scenario then it should be OK.

Comment: Like I said in the answer, it's kind of broad, and I'm not really sure what OP is trying to accomplish. But, yeah you could change the UploadChunkToServer to return a Task if you want to await upper in the call stack. (Updated the answer)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it because the paramter to ForEach is a diffrent function called by ForEach and not part of your fuction that is async - BUT - the actual solution is to not use ForEach - foreach is actually a bit shorter and doesn't have this problem

```
if (DataQueue.Count == NumberofChunksToRead)
{
    forach(var Chunk in DataQueue.ToList())
    {
        await UploadChunkToServer(Chunk);
    }
}
```